# Obtain magnetic field component from time-harmonic electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I have the electric field $\vec{E} = E_0\cos(\omega t + k_oy+\phi)\vec{a}_z$ and I need to find the magnetic field ($H$ field). I know the answer, it's $\vec{H}=-Z_0^{-1}E_0\cos(\omega t +k_0y +\phi)\vec{a}_x$. The $\vec{a}_x$ is because the magnetic component is perpendicular to the electric component, and since the wave is travelling in the $-y$ direction, it has to have $\vec a_x$ at the end. I'm not sure how they know it's $-\vec{a}_x$ though (as opposed to $+\vec{a}_x$).

I'm also not sure where the $Z_0^{-1}$ came from since I have read that it is not a safe assumption to make that $E \propto H$ ([I found that here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348095/general-relation-between-e-and-h-field-magnitudes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).

Finally, I know that it has to be a $\cos$ because the phases have to be the same.

Would someone be able to explain the parts I am not sure on?

Comment: Just use the Maxwell equations.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how exactly?

Comment: No, we do not supply solutions to homework assignments (or problems that are common homework assignments) on Physics SE. I can give a further hint: You probably can assume a vacuum and then you have an equation that gives you $\partial_t \vec H$ from which you can obtain $\vec H$ by taking the anti-derivative up to a function of $\vec r$ which can be constrained by the $\nabla \cdot \vec H = 0$ and the assumption that there is no static magnetic field.

Comment: Since it's in a vacuum does $Z_0 = \mu_0 $? If so, can I use Faraday's law (ie find the curl of E then divide by $\mu$ and integrate with respect to time)?

Comment: Yup, although I am not sure $Z_0$ is the correct constant (and all depends on the system of units you use).